# Adding to or updating a dictionary with not reference type value

Tags: c#

Before flagging this as a duplicate please double check.

I'm accumulating some stats in dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, int> stats;
```

When an event happens I update `stats`:

```
if (!stats.ContainsKey(eventName))
    stats.Add(eventName, eventValue);
else
    stats[eventName] = stats[eventName] + eventValue;
```

The problem is this code does 2 lookups for the first occurrence of an event and 3 lookups otherwise. The first occurrence is not a big deal. But those 3 lookups for updating are really bad. How could I improve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fetch the value when you check for containment. In fact, in this case you can make it unconditional:

```
int value;
stats.TryGetValue(eventName, out value);
stats[eventName] = value + eventValue;
```

This uses the fact that `value` will be 0 if there's no entry for `eventName`. You could make it explicit if you want:

```
int value;
if (!stats.TryGetValue(eventName, out value))
{
    stats.Add(eventName, eventValue);
}
else
{
    stats[eventName] = value + eventValue;
}
```

Either way, you're now down to one fetch and one set.

Alternatively, you could use `ConcurrentDictionary` and its `AddOrUpdate` method.